# SQL update a list of key/values with one statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

`table1` has fields `id`, `a`, `b`.

`table2` has fields `id`, `a`.

I want to update `table1.a` with data from `table2.a` for the records with the same ID. `table1.c` should remain unchanged. Can I do that in one single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JOIN` with `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id SET table1.a=table2.a
```

-you may want to use `INNER JOIN` instead (if you want to update only records with id existing in both tables)

Answer (score 1):

```
update table1, table2 set table1.a=table2.a where table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.a=table2.a WHERE table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id= table2.id 
SET table1.a = table2.a
```